# 2 equivalent way of applying activation functions in RNN

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, nonlinear-analysis

I don't understand why in RNN the 2 following ways of applying the activation functions are equivalent:

First way:
$$
h_t = W\sigma(h_{t-1}) + U x_t + b
$$
Second way:
$$
g_t = \sigma(Wg_{t-1} + U x_t + b)
$$

I do understand that $g_t$ and $h_t$ are not the same but I do not understand what is the relationship between the 2 and how they are equivalent.

Could you please explain it to me or give me a resource that does it?

Comment: Isn't it just $g_t=\sigma(h_t)$?

Comment: I am not sure why?

Comment: If successive values of $h_t$ are related by the first equation, then successive values of $\sigma(h_t)$ are related by the second equation.

Comment: do you have a resource for the proof, please? I am still confused

Comment: The proof I have in mind is: Define $g_t=\sigma(h_t)$. Now take $\sigma$ of both sides of the first equation. The result is the second equation.

Comment: Okay, I see it thanks